# Is mapping reduction from $\overline{A_{TM}}$ possible?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

I know $\overline{A_{TM}}$ is not Turing Recognizable (to prove it, infact, I proved its complement to be both Turing-recognizable and not decidable).

My question is, if $\overline{A_{TM}}$ is not Turing Recognizable, can I reduce $\overline{A_{TM}}$ to some language A (say $E_{TM}$) to show it is not Turing Recognizable, too? Or this does not makes sense, because it's not Turing Recognizable and so cannot exists such a reduction function/TM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notion of mapping reducibility is completely general:

Let $A, B \subseteq \Sigma^*$ be languages. $A \leq_{\mathrm{m}} B$ if there exists a computable function $f: \Sigma^* \rightarrow \Sigma^*$ such that

$$w \in A \iff f(w) \in B$$

No properties are required of $A$ or $B$.

We can use a mapping reduction from $\overline{A_{\mathsf{TM}}}$ to show that $EQ_{\mathsf{TM}}$ is not recognizable. Let $f$ be given by

$$f(\langle M,w \rangle) = \langle M', M'' \rangle$$

where $M'$ is the TM

"On input $x$ simulate $M$ on input $w$ and answer what $M$ answered"

and $M''$ is the TM that rejects every input.

Clearly, $M$ does not accept $w$ if and only if $L(M') = L(M'')$.

Comment: Thank you. My doubt is on the fact that you're taking <M, w> as input to the f function, which is not recognizable, so to me this seems strange: how can I calculate something that is not Turing recognizable? If it's Turing recognizable, I know that on "yes" instances it will halt and answer "yes", but on instances "no" I'm not sure if it will halt, but what happens with non-Turing recognizable?

Comment: The mapping reduction $f$ in my answer does not perform a secret test as to whether or not $M$ will accept $w$. 

Given a string $\langle M,w \rangle$, $f$ returns a string description of two Turing machines $M'$ and $M''$. $M'$ will simulate $M$ on input $w$ irrespective of the actual input. $M''$ will *always* reject. Neither of these machines will be constructed with knowledge of how $M$ behaves on input $w$.

Comment: And why this is not a problem? I mean, $M$ could not exists from what we know, or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "$M$ could not exist"? The function $f$ is a function from the set of strings of the form $\langle M,w \rangle$ to strings of the form $\langle M',M''\rangle$, and I have provided a definition of it. $f$ must be defined so as to be a total function, and *it is well-defined*.

Consider the function $g$ over the natural numbers defined by

$$g(x) = x^2$$

Would you now say that it may not be possible to find the value $g(7)$, for we do not know if $7$ exists ?

Comment: Because I think $7$ ($w$) could be the description of a TM $M'$ and maybe $M$ does not know what to do on $<M'>$. If you know what to do for every $w$, then to me it seems $\overline{A_{TM}}$ is decidable (or recognizable at least). What happens in this case? We map "I don't know" to "I don't know"? I'm a bit confused on this.

Comment: If $A \leq_{\mathrm{m}} B$ this simply means that there a faithful translation from the first of these two decision problems to the second one. It does not involve being able to solve $A$ or $B$. Read the definition of mapping reducibility again, please.

Comment: Moreover, I am worried by your remark that $M$ may not know what to with $M'$. Nothing of that kind is going on at all. Your misunderstanding may be more serious than I thought.

Comment: So, I'm getting "accept/reject" istances from $\overline{A_{TM}}$ and mapping to "accept/reject" istances of another problem, because even if I don't know exactly how $\overline{A_{TM}}$'s TM behave on all its inputs, I know how the language is, it's more generic. Is this right? And when you say "On input $x$ simulate $M$ on input $w$ and answer what $M$ answered", if $M$ does not halt on some $w$, same does $M'$ on every $x$.

Comment: We know the definitions of $\overline{A_{\mathsf{TM}}}$ and $EQ_{\mathsf{TM}}$, and those are all we need to check that the proposed mapping reduction from $\overline{A_{\mathsf{TM}}}$ to $EQ_{\mathsf{TM}}$ is faithful. If an $\overline{A_{\mathsf{TM}}}$ instance $\langle M,w\rangle$ satisfies that $M$ does not accept $w$, then for the constructed $\langle M',M'' \rangle$ we have that $L(M') = L(M'')$. If an $\overline{A_{\mathsf{TM}}}$ instance $\langle M,w\rangle$ satisfies that $M$ accepts $w$, then $L(M') \neq L(M'')$.